# Laravel: How to insert data in case of three way pivot table using attach method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, insert, pivot-table, record

Here are my tables

**boards**

```
id
board_name
```

**classes**

```
id
class_name
```

**subjects**

```
id
subject_name
```

**board_classes**

```
id
board_id
class_id
```

**board_class_subjects**

```
id
board_id
class_id
subject_id
```

I written following association in my models

**Board.php**

```
public function classes()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Clas','board_classes','board_id','class_id');
}
```

**Clas.php**

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject','board_class_subjects','class_id', 'subject_id');
}
```

I am trying to insert a sample data in pivot table `board_class_subjects` using following code:

```
$data = array();
$data['board_id'] = 1;
$data['class_id'] = 1;
$data['subject_id'] = 1;

$pivot = Board::find(1);
$pivot->subjects()->attach($data);
```

But getting error shown below:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::subjects()
```

I know that there is no method with the name **subjects** in my **Board** model but not sure how to achieve it so that i could use `attach` method to insert data in `board_class_subjects` pivot table. Should i add another method with the name **sections** in Board model similar to "classes" method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `Board` has nothing to do with the relation from `Clas(s)` to `Subject`. However you can treat `board_id` just like any other *additional pivot column* and insert it like documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

```
$subjectId = 1;
$boardId = 1;
$class = Clas::find(1);
$class->subjects()->attach($subjectId, ['board_id' => $boardId]);
```

Alternatively, if you already have gathered all the id's you can also just make an insert on the pivot table. (`attach()` doesn't do much else anyways)

```
$data = array();
$data['board_id'] = 1;
$data['class_id'] = 1;
$data['subject_id'] = 1;
DB::table('board_class_subjects')->insert($data);
```

Comment: If you say there is no need to create subjects() method in Clas.php then i get the following error BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::subjects()

Isn't there other way of inserting record using attach method ?

Comment: I did never say that there's no need for `subjects()` in `Clas`. But in your example you are using the relation between `Board` and `Subject`. Just leave the relations like you have them

Comment: So in this case how would i add data in pivot table. I am not rigid of using Board only. But just checking out if there is any other way to insert data into that pivot table. I actually want to use attach method instead of DB::table ?

Comment: Since Laravel doesn't know triple pivot tables and you are you using a construct of two belongsToMany relations you will always have to attach it to one relation and add the other foreign key as shown in my first example.

Comment: As per your first example, $pivot->subjects() will not work as there is no direct relation between board and subject. A Board may have multiple classes and a class may have multiple subjects but the pivot table contain association of all in which board_id, class_id and subject_id is kept in the table...Can you please send me chat invite to discuss further?

Comment: Ah I see. I just thought `Board` had `subjects()` because it was like that in your question. Try the updated answer instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71158/discussion-between-neeraj-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a solution many-to-many relation with pivot table **board_classes** and **subjects**

**board_classes**

```
id
board_id
class_id
```

**board_class_subjects**

```
id
board_class_id
subject_id
```